# Unable to find Translation Manager TmBinaryEndpointV2

Tags: event-system, workflow, translation-manager

Trying automate translation jobs within workflow from Sites 9.1 to rename process instances to add the translation job name.

```
        ProcessInstance processInstance = new ProcessInstance(subject.Process.Id, subject.Session);
        processInstance.Title = string.Format("[{0}] [{1}] [{2}]", language, pageName, title);
        processInstance.Save();
```

Followed steps in solution for [Unable to find Translation Manager TmBinaryEndpoint](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/19110/29) for 8.5

Added App.config and copied   <system.serviceModel> section from TcmWorkFlowAgent.exe.config

In OnActivityInstanceStartPre Event Handler I get the tcmid of the item in workflow

```
        string itemid = "tcm:0-0-0";
        foreach (WorkItem workItem in subject.WorkItems)
        {
            itemid = workItem.Subject.Id;
            break;
        }
```

Then try to get a tmClient

```
            using (var tmClient = new SessionAwareTmServiceClient("TmBinaryEndpointV2"))
            {
                TcmItemTranslationInfoData ti = tmClient.GetTcmItemTranslationInfo(itemid);
                jobTitle = ti.ItemTitle;
            }
```

The code fails with exception

> Could not find endpoint element with name 'TmBinaryEndpointV2' and contract 'Tridion.TranslationManager.V2.TmService.Client.ISessionAwareTmService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this name could be found in the client element.

Are there any extra steps required to use the TmClient on Sites 9.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is much better to use Translation Manager API instead of WCF service inside event handlers.

Reference **Tridion.TranslationManager.dll** and **Tridion.TranslationManager.V2.dll** in your project.

Then create ITmSession in your event handler using this example:

```
private void OnActivityInstanceStartPre(ActivityInstance subject, StartActivityEventArgs e, EventPhases phase)
{
    using (ITmSession tmSession = Tridion.TranslationManager.V2.TmSessionFactory.Create(subject.Session))
    {
        // tmSession will give you full access to TM API
    }
}
```

Comment: Given that WCF error has 1.97 million results in Google.
I am happy to ditch that solution for one that works.
Once I found the Tridion.TranslationManager.dll in the GAC and copied to my references, The solution worked. Thanks for a great answer.

Answer (score 0):

In general, event handlers are executed in the same process as the one which triggers them. Many events are triggered from the Core Service, meaning that the event handlers will run in either the `TcmServiceHost.exe` process (for net.tcp-based Core Service endpoints) or `w3wp.exe` (the TCM AppPool to be precise, for HTTP-based Core Service endpoints).

As of 9.5, events may also be triggered from the new Core Service REST, which also runs in the TCM AppPool in IIS.

Furthermore, events can be triggered from the TCM Publisher Service (`TcmPublisher.exe` process) and even from the Translation Manager Service (`Tridion.TranslationManager.Service.exe` process).

So: you see, it's quite challenging to rely on app/web configuration in event handlers: you may have to change several app/web config files (and hopefully you remember which ones you modified after an upgrade).  You could consider putting your configuration in `machine.config`.

In case of Activity Instance Start event: these can be expected to be triggered from `TcmServiceHost.exe` (most likely) or IIS.  That means that the configuration of the TmBinaryEndpointV2 should be either in `TcmServiceHost.exe.config` or `machine.config`.